# Tmux vertical split looks bad

Tags: kali-linux, tmux

Whenever I try and split my `tmux` window vertically, the border looks like this whenever I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or if an error occurs. I'm running Kali Linux 2021.1 on VirtualBox. Has anyone encountered this type of thing before?

[image]

Comment: Switch the `zsh` prompt theme and it'll stop happening, I'd guess.

Comment: Side note: it's [horizontal split](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/213).

Comment: Some character(s) in the prompts on the left are wider than others. `tmux` assumes they are like other characters but your terminal emulator renders them wider. This moves the rest of the line to the right. The behavior possibly depends on the font used. Terminals work best with characters of the same width, so the display is a regular grid. Using fancy prompt and/or fancy font is asking for trouble like this. This is not an answer because it's just a hypothesis, not researched enough (I don't use fancy prompts/fonts and I'm not going to).

Answer (score 0):

By changing the character between user and hostname to something less fancy fixes the issue. Kamil was right in assuming it had to do with a wider character.